# How large is a typical contemporary hagada commentary?

Tags: number, jewish-books, passover-seder-hagada, writing-printing, publications

In a contemporary published hagada with commentary, how many total words does the commentary typically comprise? (For comparison, ["Hagada - Mi Yodeya?"](http://s.tk/miyodeya), in its current form, weighs in at about 14,000 words of commentary.)

More broadly:

If someone wanted to bring a manuscript for a hagada commentary to publishers to consider for publication as a full-fledged hagada, what characteristics would the manuscript ideally have, to be taken as seriously as possible?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there is a "typical" commentary by which to judge some standard length. I have an old copy of a Haggadah published by the Staten Island Yeshivah from 1947, which is pamphlet-length in its entirety, despite having a good deal of commentary throughout, and the *["Torat Hyim" Haggadah](http://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/haggadah-shel-pesach-torahs-chaim---mosad-harav-kook-S309755.html)*, which is over 200 pages long, despite its mostly short commentaries included. Of course, in the latter, each passage of the Haggadah has several commentators' writings.

My personal feeling is that a Haggadah's commentary ought to be engaging to the reader, however long it may be. To the point, the [Nechama Leibowitz Haggadah](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9657108381), which my wife favors, is 159 total pages and contains, "over 100 analytical questions relating to the Passover Seder and the Exodus from Egypt...extracted from Nechama's renowned weekly Torah study sheets."  Yet its style keeps the reader engaged, and it can be used to study from in preparation for the Seder or to pull up a quick Devar Torah at the Seder itself.

Answer (score 3):

Two things.  First the various commentaries vary greatly in length.  For instance Rav Benayahu Shmueli published one(his shortest) Shm'a Beni at about 30k words(of commentary) and his third(and longest) Musar Avikha at three times that.  The same can be said with the various commentaries by famous Rabbanim through the ages.

As far as publishing, you will find that most often these are self-published.  I don't know of a commentary that was published in the lifetime of the Rav by a publisher.  Usually the individual pays for their own publication and distribution.  In a few generations when it has become a classic(G-d willing) a publisher may pick it up.

Comment: Speaking of commentaries of different lengths, we can't forget the king of expanded commentaries: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%97%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%90